# Galoisian perspective on local system tamely ramified along a smooth divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, galois-theory, etale-cohomology, constructible-sheaves

This question is about (1.7.8) and (1.7.11) in Deligne’s Weil II paper.

Let $X$ be a regular scheme and $D\subset X$ a smooth principal divisor cut out by the function $t$. Let $\mathcal F$ be a locally constant étale sheaf of finite sets on $X-D$ tamely ramified along $D$. Let $n$ be an integer inversible on $X$ and let $\pi:X_n\to X$ be obtained by adjoining $t^{1/n}$ to the ring of functions on $X$; $X_n$ is regular and $\pi$ is totally ramified over $D$ and étale away from $D$. The identification $\pi^{-1}(D)_{\mathrm{red}}=D$ gives a section of the projection $\pi^{-1}(D)\to D$; on functions this section sends $t^{1/n}$ to zero. The group $\mu_n$ of $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity acts on $X_n$: given $r\in\mu_n$, multiplication $t^{1/n}\mapsto rt^{1/n}$ gives an automorphism of $X_n$. By Abhyankar’s lemma, there is an $n$ invertible on $X$ so that $\pi^*\mathcal F$ extends to a local system on all of $X_n$. The restriction of $\pi^*\mathcal F$ to $D$ then gives a local system on $D$ called $\mathcal F[D]$.
The action of $\mu_n$ on $X_n$ fixes $\pi^{-1}(D)$ pointwise and induces the identity on $\pi^{-1}(D)_{\mathrm{red}}$. Therefore the action of $\mu_n$ on $X_n$ induces an action on $\mathcal F[D]$ by transport of structure.

The Galoisian perspective on this is to replace $X$ by the spectrum of its henselization at the generic point of $D$ with function field $K$ and residue field $k$ and let $X_1$ denote the spectrum of the strict henselization with function field $K_1$ and residue field $k_1$ a separable closure of $k$. Let $\mathbf{L}$ denote the set of primes not equal to the characteristic of $k$. There is an exact sequence
$$1\to\hat{\mathbf{Z}}_{\mathbf L}(1)\to\pi_1^{\text{mod}}(X-D,\operatorname{Spec}(\overline K))\to\operatorname{Gal}(k_1/k)\to1.$$
If $K_2$ denotes the extension of $K_1$ obtained by adjoining all $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of $t$ for $n$ invertible on $X$, then $\pi_1^{\text{mod}}(X-D,\operatorname{Spec}(\overline K))=\operatorname{Gal}(K_2/K)$, and compatible choices of $t$ and $t^{1/n}$ split this extension, as $\operatorname{Gal}(k_1/k)$ can then be identified with the subgroup of $\operatorname{Gal}(K_2/K)$ fixing the $t^{1/n}$. If one identifies $\mathcal F$ with the action of $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline K/K)$ on its stalk $F$ at $\operatorname{Spec}(\overline K)$, then in this way one obtains an action of $\operatorname{Gal}(k_1/k)$ on $F$; i.e. a sheaf on $\operatorname{Spec}(k)$. Deligne says moreover from this data one obtains a $\operatorname{Gal}(k_1/k)$-equivariant action of $\hat{\mathbf{Z}}_{\mathbf L}(1)$ on $F$.

How to deduce this action without proceeding via the geometric construction?

Comment: Whenever we have an exact sequence of groups $1 \to H \to G \to K \to 1$, if the exact sequence splits, we can express $G$ as the semidirect product $H \rtimes K$, and then a $G$-action on something is equivalent to a $K$-action together with a $K$-equivariant $H$-action. Do you want an explanation of why the exact sequence you wrote splits? If not, what do youw ant?

Comment: I see why the sequence splits, but I don’t understand why a $G$-representation is the same as a $K$-representation with a $K$-equivariant $H$-action. I understand $K$-equivariant to mean that $h^{-1}k^{-1}hk$ acts by the identity. By Mackey theory ($H$ is abelian) an irreducible $G$-representation is induced from the data of a character $\chi$ of $H$ and an irreducible representation of the subgroup of $K$ fixing $\chi$. When this subgroup is not all of $K$, there is a $k\in K$ so that $\chi(k^{-1}hk)\ne\chi(h)$ for some $h\in H$. Then how is the $H$-action $K$-equivariant?

Comment: That's not what $K$-equivariance means in this context. $K$-equivariance means that $k h k^{-1} \cdot k $ acts the same as $k \cdot h$ where $k$ is viewed as an element of $K$ and $k h k^{-1}$ and $h$ are viewed as elements of $H$.

Comment: This makes sense since the group scheme $\mu_n$ itself carries an action of $\operatorname{Gal}(K_1/K)$. Thanks!